# How to detect focus on link elements and form input fields when activated with Tab key?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, focus, accessibility, onfocus

I want to detect when user focuses a link or input field by pressing the Tab key. Does anyone know of a way to do this? I have tried using the onFocus event, but it does not seem to work.

(I am not using jQuery, and I want to detect focus on links as well, so the similar question 16144611 is not the same as this one.)

Comment: "I have tried using the onFocus event, but it does not seem to work" can you elaborate and perhaps give some code? Because it sounds like `focus` event is exactly what you need here.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Robin. The problems to be that the focus event does not bubble up, while I was trying to add a global focus handler.

Comment: thanks. Again it's hard to directly help without seeing code. I've never personally come across this behaviour of the `focus` event, but checking on MDN not only confirms this is correct, but finds 2 simple alternatives to get round it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event#event_delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By combining `keyUp` and [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) we can see if an element is currently focused.

We then need to look for the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on keyup and you have a reasonable start at a solution.

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('a, input');

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
   // check the key code
   const code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
   if(code == 9 && els.length){
     checkFocus();
   }
   
});


function checkFocus(){
   // loop all elements (within our selector at the start) and see if they match the document.activeElement  
   for (const el of els) {
     if(document.activeElement == el){
       console.log("focused tag:" + el.tagName);
     }
   }
}
```

```html
<button>Click me for focus, I am not checked</button>
<a href="#">Focused Link</a>
<label for="input1">I am also reported</label>
<input id="input1">
<button>Another button not announced</button>
```

Note that if you **only ever want to check for links and inputs only** a more efficient way to check would be:

```js
const els = ['A', 'INPUT'];

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
   // check the key code
   const code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
   if(code == 9 && els.length){
     checkFocus();
   }
   
});


function checkFocus(){
   // by checking the tagName we only have to do 2 loops no matter how many links or inputs there are on a page, which is far more efficient. The downside is it will check **every** link and input on the page. You would access the element with document.activeElelemnt instead if you need to know which item was focused.
   for (const el of els) {
     if(document.activeElement.tagName == el){
       console.log("focused tag:" + document.activeElement.tagName);
     }
   }
}
```

```html
<button>Click me for focus, I am not checked</button>
<a href="#">Focused Link</a>
<label for="input1">I am also reported</label>
<input id="input1">
<button>Another button not announced</button>
```